# How can I show the following contraction of the electromagnetic field strength and its dual?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, standard-model, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics

Given the electromagnetic field strength $F^{\mu\nu}$, and its dual $$\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu} =\dfrac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta},$$
how can I show that
$$\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}F_{\nu\rho} = -\dfrac{1}{4}\delta^\mu_\rho  \tilde{F}^{\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}   ??? $$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A possible proof can be:

From lorentz invariance you have

$
\tilde{F}^{\mu \nu} F_{\rho \nu}= C \delta_{\rho}^{\mu} , \quad C \in \mathbb{R}
$

now taking the trace both side you obtain $C$

$
\tilde{F}^{\alpha \nu} F_{\alpha \nu}= C \delta_{\alpha}^{\alpha}= 4 C
$
so

$
\tilde{F}^{\mu \nu} F_{\rho \nu}= \frac{1}{4} \delta_{\rho}^{\mu} \tilde{F}^{\alpha \beta} F_{\alpha \beta}
$
finally switching the index ($\rho \leftrightarrow \nu$) and using $F_{\rho \nu}=-F_{\nu \rho}$ you obtain

$
\tilde{F}^{\mu \nu} F_{\nu \rho}= -\frac{1}{4} \delta_{\rho}^{\mu} \tilde{F}^{\alpha \beta} F_{\alpha \beta}
$

Comment: Thank you! I do not understand the nature of your ansatz. Would not be necessary to verify the symmetry in $\mu$ and $\rho$ before proposing the delta on the ansatz?

Comment: No, it's the only Lorentz invariant symbol. Lorentz group have only $\epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \gamma}$ and $ \delta_{\mu}^{\nu}$ like invariant symbols. See some reference on Lorentz group for details.

Comment: I don't see why $\tilde{F}^{\mu \nu} F_{\rho \nu}$ must be proportional to the identity tensor.  Your proof says that if it *is*, it must be proportional with a factor of $- \frac{1}{4} \tilde{F} F$, but why couldn't it be proportional to some other tensor of rank (1,1)?